# Какая лучшая практика использования try-except в функциях?

Tags: python, python-3.x, исключения, обработка-ошибок

В каких случаях нужно использовать блоки `try-except` в функциях, а в каких их не рекомендованно или вообще нельзя использовать?

Как лучше перехватывать и обрабатывать исключения и ошибки - с блоком или без? Интересует *best practice* для разработчика.

---

Уточняющий [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1227611/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-try-exception-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-python/1227695#comment2150073_1227611).

Я и курсы проходил и сам использую try exception во всех функциях. Недавно при работе с deno (JS) опытный разработчик, сказал, чтобы я не использовал `try-catch` вообще, кроме случая код я не могу предусмотреть все возможные ошибки.

В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос - а на сколько правильно и оправданно использования `try-except` во всех функциях в которых идет вызов каких-то библиотек?

Пример кода функции с try except. На сколько он корректный и оптимальный с точки зрения обработки исключений?

```
async def GetPrices(symbol, exchange, limit=10):

    sellPrice = None
    buyPrice = None

    while True:
        try:
            orderBook = await exchange.fetchOrderBook(symbol, limit=limit)
            bidsPrice, bidsAmount = map(list, zip(*orderBook['bids'])) 
            asksPrice, asksAmount = map(list, zip(*orderBook['asks'])) 
            
            buyPrice = np.average(bidsPrice, weights = bidsAmount)
            sellPrice = np.average(asksPrice, weights = asksAmount)
            break

        except ccxt.RequestTimeout as e:
            log.error("Exchange %s  %s  %s", exchange.name, '[' + type(e).__name__ + ']', str(e)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.DDoSProtection as e:
            log.error("Exchange %s  %s  %s", exchange.name, '[' + type(e).__name__ + ']', str(e)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.ExchangeNotAvailable as e:
            log.error("Exchange %s  %s  %s", exchange.name, '[' + type(e).__name__ + ']', str(e)[0:200])
            # will retry
        except ccxt.ExchangeError as e:
            log.error("Exchange %s  %s  %s", exchange.name, '[' + type(e).__name__ + ']', str(e)[0:200])
            break  # won't retry
        except Exception as e:
            log.error("Exchange %s  %s  %s", exchange.name, '[' + type(e).__name__ + ']', str(e)[0:200])
            break  # won't retry

    return sellPrice, buyPrice
```

Comment: Качественный ответ на данный вопрос потянет на немаленькую главу книги по Python. Что вам мешает загуглить `python exception handling best practices` и почитать по ссылкам?

Comment: @maxU - везде написано как использовать. Я и курсы проходил и сам использую try exception во всех функциях. Недавно при работе с deno (javascript) опытный разработчик, сказал, чтобы я не использовал try catch вообще, кроме случая код я не могу предусмотреть все возможные ошибки. В связи с этим у меня возник вопрос - а на сколько правильно и оправданно использования try exception во всех функциях в которых идет вызов каких-то библиотек?

Comment: Не стоит писать комментарии. На вопросы в уточняющих комментариях лучше сразу добавлять информацию прямо в вопрос.

Comment: [EAFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Exceptions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После того как вы уточнили вопрос в комментарии, я думаю я смогу дать несколько советов по правильному, на мой взгляд, использованию обработки исключений.

По-моему перехватывать нужно только заведомо известные исключения, которые мы хотим явно обработать и для которых мы очень четко себе представляем, что делать после того как исключение сработало.

Во всех остальных случаях нужно либо не обрабатывать исключения или же опять вызывать `raise` для повторного вызова исключительной ситуации из блока `except ...`. Часто начинающие разработчики пишут обработчики исключительных ситуаций в таком стиле:

```
# NOTE: DONT'T DO THIS !!!
try:
    #do_something...
except Exception as e:
    print("видимо что-то пошло не так")
```

Это очень плохой стиль, т.к. после такой обработки ошибки мы совершенно слепы и не понимаем, что пошло не так и в каком месте и как с этим бороться. Такая обратка ошибок приносит гораздо больше вреда, чем пользы.

Пример осмысленной обработки исключений:

```
def to_float(num_str: str) -> float:
    try:
        return float(str(num_str).replace(",", "."))
    except ValueError as exc:
        print(f"Значение [{num_str}] не может быть преобразовано в вещественное число")
```

тесты:

```
In [52]: to_float(1.23)
Out[52]: 1.23

In [53]: to_float("3.14")
Out[53]: 3.14

In [54]: to_float("1,23")
Out[54]: 1.23

In [55]: to_float("nan")
Out[55]: nan

In [57]: to_float("1e-3")
Out[57]: 0.001

In [74]: to_float("10a")
Значение [10a] не может быть преобразовано в вещественное число
```

Comment: А ниже приведенный код - приемлем для случаев, когда сбой в самой функции (например закачки данных), не должен влиять на работу всего приложения?


except Exception as e:
    log.error(e)
 return

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, можете более подробно описать ситуацию?

Comment: добавил пример кода в вопрос.

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, я бы на вашем месте воспользовался [декоратором retry](https://github.com/invl/retry) - это значительно упростит код

Comment: но он чень старый. будет ли он поддерживаться в новых версиях python и будет ли на него поддержка вообще?

Comment: И будет ли он корректно работать с asyncio корректно? а идея мне нравится

Comment: не знаю, нужно попробовать... Можно поискать альтернативный модуль поновее - https://github.com/pnpnpn/retry-decorator